The choose file button is not responding when trying to upload an image file
I created a project in Laravel 10, with listings table, and everything is running okay, except the
Choose file button: it's not responding at all. So I'm not able to load an image for my listing.
I tried to change the image format or extension, but uselessly.
The definition in listingcontroller seems to be written like this:
if($request->hasFile('logo')) {
    $formFields['logo'] = $request->file('logo')->store ('logos', 'public');
}

I should have a folder created on storage/app/logos now, and the image must be loaded inside it, but the button not responding at all;
Definition for the creat.blade.php file:
<div class="mb-6">
    <label for="logo" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">
    Company Logo
    </label>
    <input type="file" class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full" name="logo" />
    @error('logo')
    <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}}</p>
    @enderror
</div>

I am using the Model::unguard(); method in the AppServiceProvider file.
Everything looks okay. How do I solve this?
